# sysibm.char(0.1) giving different result in IBM DB2 v 10.5 and 11.1

Tags: db2

```
select sysibm.char(0.1) from dual
```

in Db2 10.5 this gives 0.1

```
select sysibm.char(0.1) from dual
```

in Db2 11.1 this gives .1

Is there a change in the char function between version 10.5 and 11.1 of DB2 LUW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change was made in DB2 9.7 but only affected new databases. If your DB2 10.5 database has been upgraded from a database that was originally on 9.5 or earlier, but your 11.1 database is new, that would explain the difference.

The database parameter dec_to_char_fmt controls this behaviour 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0054719.html

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense my 10.5 DB2 was originally upgraded from 9.5 and 11.1 DB is a new one. i see the parameter is defaulted to new in the 11.1 database.